# Duplicate data in Plotly treemap

Tags: python, charts, plotly, treemap

I am trying to visualize a call stack with Plotlys treemap. I have a Pandas dataframe with the columns "Function Name", "Parent ID which called the function", "Duration".

When displaying the treemap I was expecting to have one root "Main" function which basically contains the rest of the nested functions. Instead I am getting a "Main" function containing "Function H" and then a second root node "Function H" with the same label and duration with its childrend. And this is for all the nodes.

Why aren't the children of "Function H" withing the original node in "Main"?

I have following code which can be run in Jupyther Lab:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd


data = {'parent': ['Function A', 'Function A', 'Function A', 'Function A', 'Function A', 'Function A', 'Function B', 'Function B', 'Function B', 'Function B', 'Function C', 'Function C', 'Function D', 'Function E', 'Function F', 'Main', 'Function H', 'Function H', 'Function H', 'Function H', 'Function F', 'Function A', 'Function H', 'Function B'],
        'function': ['Function C', 'Function D', 'Function F', 'Function I', 'Function J', 'Function K', 'Function A', 'Function L', 'Function M', 'Function N', 'Function C', 'Function O', 'Function P', 'Function Q', 'Function C', 'Function H', 'Function B', 'Function R', 'Function D', 'Function E', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other'],
        'duration': [3.0, 1.0, 169.0, 8.0, 3.0, 29.0, 272.0, 6.0, 7.0, 4.0, 60.0, 60.0, 3.0, 1.0, 60.0, 1100.0, 636.0, 10.0, 3.0, 1.0, 109.0, 59.0, 450.0, 347.0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False) 

fig = px.treemap(df, path=['parent', 'function'], values='duration')

fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(cornerradius=5))
fig.show()
```

This is how the output looks:
[image: Output]

I was trying to create something like this:
[image: Expected output]
The example data is kind of boring as there aren't too many branches, but that is the only data I have at the moment.

I already tried adding a root node and then adding that to the path as well, but that didn't really change anything.

I don't really have to display the data in a treemap, i just couldn't find anything else that displays the data in a nested manner with the durations visible by size.

So im either looking for a fix to display the treemap the way I want or another chart type which can display nested data with weight information.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is that the data structure is not a tree structure, and if you remove the main row and add the whole specification to the path specification, you get the intended result. Please check the reference for [details](https://plotly.com/python/treemaps/#treemap-of-a-rectangular-dataframe-with-plotlyexpress).

```
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df[df['parent'] != 'Main']

fig = px.treemap(df, path=[px.Constant('Main'), 'parent', 'function'], values='duration')

fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.update_traces(marker=dict(cornerradius=5))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, but it seems I was a bit unclear about what I was expecting as output, so I added another image to make it clearer. If you think this is not possible to display with a treemap, I would also be very grateful just to know what type of chart would support my needs.

Comment: I have checked the updated content of the question. I see that the current data structure is inadequate. The first level is Main and The second level is 'FunctionH' and the third level should be the current data frame, excluding FunctionH.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how the data would have to be structured? I can't really imagine it at the moment.

Comment: If you just want to see the structure, you can understand it by running the following code. `df = pd.DataFrame(data);df = df[df['parent'] != 'Main'];df['level1'] = ['Function H']*len(df);df = df[df['parent'] != 'Function H']`