# python plotly treemap: how to use ids and treat duplicated names

Tags: python, plotly, treemap

How do I correctly use `treemap` and the key `ids` to represent a hierarchical data set that contains duplicated names?

To the most basic, I would like to reproduce a treemap similar as the following:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.treemap(
    parents = ["",    "Anna","Anna", "Bert",  "Bert", "Belen", "Belen",  "Belen", "Cristiano"],
    names =   ["Anna","Bert","Belen","Charlie","Chris","Carlos","Camila","Cristiano", "Diego"],
)
fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.show()
```

which produces this figure:

[image: desired result]

Problem 1: if a name is duplicated, e.g. suppose "Carlos" appears both under "Belen" and under "Bert", then (due to the ambiguity) the figure is blank. To solve the ambiguity, I will use the key `ids`.

Suppose, I have a dataset (teams.csv):

```
ltree,name,parent
,Anna,
Bert,Bert,Anna
Belen,Belen,Anna
Bert-Carlos,Carlos,Bert
Bert-Chris,Chris,Bert
Belen-Carlos,Carlos,Belen
Belen-Camila,Camila,Belen
Belen-Cristiano,Cristiano,Belen
Belen-Cristiano-Diego,Diego,Cristiano
```

where the first column is a path of ltree type (from a Postgres database) which I would use as `ids` in the plotly treemap method.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("teams.csv")
df = df.fillna('')
fig = px.treemap(df,
    parents=df.parent,
    names=df.name,
    ids=df.ltree,
    # path=[px.Constant('Anna'),'parent', 'name']
)
fig.show()
```

which produces a blank view.

Problem 2: If I remove the last row from the csv data set,

```
df = df.fillna('').head(-1)
```

then treemap is able to render a figure, yet incomplete.

I have tried to change the ltree path format like `Belen-Cristiano-Diego` to `Root-Belen-Cristiano-Diego` or ("Anna" instead of "Root").

I have also tried the solution from the post [Duplicate data in Plotly treemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75806947/duplicate-data-in-plotly-treemap) removing the first row (i.e. the root):

```
df = df.fillna('').tail(-1)
fig = px.treemap(df,
    path=[px.Constant('Anna'),'parent', 'name']
)
fig.show()
```

which renders a figure but it is the wrong hierarchy.

[image: incorrect result]

I don't know what I am doing incorrectly with the `ids`, as the ltree path has unique values or how should I format / edit the ltree path.

Answer (score 0):

As `ids` you can use the same items as the names, except on the duplicates, because the `ids` must be unique - obviously. On the duplicates, you use a different and unique label. Using the path as a id for the duplicates is more than fine.

In practice:

```
dup = df['name'].duplicated()
df.loc[~dup, 'ltree'] = df.loc[~dup, 'name']
```

meaning that you find the location `dup` of the duplicates, and use the names as id's where the names are not duplicated. In short, this sets the column `ltree` equal `name` almost everywhere and will leave the record `Belen-Carlos` unchanged.

```
ltree,name,parent
...
Carlos,Carlos,Bert
Chris,Chris,Bert
Belen-Carlos,Carlos,Belen
```

Finally, you render the figure:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = df.fillna('')
fig = px.treemap(df,
    parents=df.parent,
    names=df.name,
    ids=df.ltree,
)
fig.update_traces(root_color="lightgrey")
fig.show()
```

Caveat about my answer: reading the documentation at https://plotly.com/python/reference/treemap, I admit that I still don't fully understand how `ids` works or should be used, and this answer does not follow exactly the instructions there.